# How to add CSRF disable for specific URL in Spring Web Flux Basic Authentication (Reactive Programming)

Tags: java, spring-webflux

How to add CSRF disable for specific URL in Spring Web Flux Basic Authentication (Reactive Programming)

```java
  @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf().disable() // Here we need to add
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
         .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(getURLsForDisabledCSRF()).and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().build();
    }

    public NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher getURLsForDisabledCSRF() {
        return new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                exchange -> ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/api/**")
                        .matches(exchange));
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).